# Facing run-time Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException exception in VS 2019 preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run extension on visual studio 2019 preview and i am getting following errors.

1. System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'DynamicOrderPrecedenceDataSourceImporter`3: 54884337' closed because of an exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Class A". ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.IConfiguredProjectServices Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ConfiguredProject.get_Services()'.
2. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Class B". ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.IUnconfiguredProjectServices Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProject.get_Services()'.

Please help in resolving above errors

Regards,

Comment: How are you referencing the ProjectSystem APIs?  I think there was a breaking change in between VS2017 and the first VS2019 preview around this particular API.

Comment: I am trying to use same code which was written for VS 2017 in VS 2019. few examples how i am trying to use. 1. IUnconfiguredProjectCommonServices CommonProjectServices;
CommonProjectServices.ActiveConfiguredProject.Services; // getting exception here


2. UnconfiguredProject unconfiguredProject;
unconfiguredProject.Services;  // getting exception here



3. IProjectService projectService;
projectService.Services;     // getting exception here

Answer (score 1):

In VS2019, there was a breaking change around this API.  If you compare the reference assemblies from the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem/) nuget package from the latest 15.x version to 16.x, you'll see the change:

[image: Comparison of signatures on UnconfiguredProject.get_Services method]

Notice how in 15.x it was IUnconfiguredProjectServices and in 16.x it is now UnconfiguredProjectServices (without the I).

You'll need to update your references for VS2019.

Comment: 16.x is still pre-release and i am still using 15.8.243 in my code. Can you also help in provide any sample code which i can refer ?

Comment: There is no code change required (your code would still use `.Services`), but for VS2019, you need to update how you reference this assembly.  If you're using the NuGet package, update to the latest package when you build for VS2019; if you're referencing the assemblies directly, you'll need to have separate copies as well.

Comment: i have updated the dependency to pre release version and it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: However in VS 2019 preview visual studio dll's reference is not working which was given in VS 2017. I have to manually delete the non working references and re add  in VS 2019 like i have added reference for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor" and in VS 2019 it couldn't identified so i have to delete and re browse the dll. What could be the reason of that ? any idea ?

Comment: @golf89 I'm not sure exaclty what references you're referring to, but there are numerous breaking (incompatible) changes between VS2017 and VS2019.  These issues are likely a result of that.  You'll probably need separate builds to customize the references for each version of VS that you target.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried a lot of things and this one finally solved my issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/660096/service-fabric-project-not-loading.html

(0) The exception happend when I tried to open project, it stayed "unloaded" and exception occured
(1) Restart computer, make sure not Visual Studio instance is running
(2) Delete (not just for the safe matter rename it :-)) mentioned folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\gramtlyq.e04 (about 6k files!)
(3) Run Developer Console for VS2019 and run: devenv /UpdateConfiguration
(4) Open project was OK now

Good luck with this mysterious bug to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

My case was a little different. I had tried to upgrade a project from .NET Core 3.0 to 3.1. I received no errors or warnings when I updated the version until and the next time I closed and reopened the project. I tried many different fixes and none of them had worked. My solution and the projects still compiled properly the entire time.

What finally ended up fixing my issue was to change the version back to .NET Core 3.0 and redo the upgrade to 3.1. I do not know why this was a fix and I haven't seen that suggested anywhere on any other forums. Hopefully it helps someone.